# Matlab - Finding values within a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

How can I find the row that have all the values from A into the matrix B and display the index of the rows using Matlab?

```
A= [2 5 6];

B=[1 2 4 9 10 15 27 30; 
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8; 
   1 2 3 5 6 9 22 101; 
   2 4 5 6 14 20 22 23]
```

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify: in your example you would get rows 2,3 and 4 as output? Or does the `[2 5 6]` vector need to be contiguous?

Comment: All good now, The answer bellow was what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) in `3D` -

```
ind = find(all(any(bsxfun(@eq,B,permute(A,[1 3 2])),2),3))
```

With `bsxfun` again, but keeping it in `2D` -

```
ind = find(sum(reshape(any(bsxfun(@eq,B(:),A(:).'),2),size(B)),2)==numel(A))
```

With [`ismember`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) -

```
ind = find(sum(reshape(ismember(B(:),A(:)),size(B)),2)==numel(A))
```

With [`pdist2`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) from [`Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/stats/index.html) -

```
ind = find(sum(reshape(any(pdist2(B(:),A(:))==0,2),size(B)),2)==numel(A))
```

With [`knnsearch`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/stats/knnsearch.html) again from `Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox`-

```
[~,dists] = knnsearch(A(:),B(:))
ind = find(sum(reshape(dists==0,size(B)),2)==numel(A))
```

---

Sample run -

```
A =
     2     5     6
B =
     1     2     4     9    10    15    27    30
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
     1     2     3     5     6     9    22   101
     2     4     5     6    14    20    22    23
ind =
     2
     3
     4
```

Comment: @Emanuel Consider accepting it, by clicking on the checkmark next to the solution. Read more about it [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Comment: And if I have three or four matrices to search through B and get the index similar?
A= [2 5 6];
C=[4 5 6];
D=[8 9 10; 2 9 19];
B=[1 2 4 9 10 15 27 30; 
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8; 
   1 2 3 5 6 9 22 101; 
   2 4 5 6 14 20 22 23]
How can I do this?