# Efficiently perform 1D linear interpolation without for loops

Tags: arrays, matlab, linear-interpolation

I am trying to perform linear interpolation in MATLAB using a specific precision.
I was wondering if there is an efficient way to write the linear interpolation function in MATLAB so that it doesn't require for-loops and runs very fast?

I want to modify the incoming data to a specific bitwidth (using the quantize() function), then I also want to make sure that all of the intermediate operations are done using another bitwidth.

Right now I am using the following equation to perform linear interpolation at specific points xq given the values y at points x. I have not included the quantize() commands below for clarity.

```
for j = 1:length(xq)
  for k = 1:length(x)
    if ((x(k) <= xq(j)) && (xq(j) < x(k+1)))
      yq(j) = y(k) + (y(k+1) - y(k))/(x(k+1)-x(k)) * (xq(j)-x(k));
      break;
    end
  end
end
```

Here is something that matches the dimensions of my input data. Also, I have to do this linear interpolation lots of times (over 200), so it needs to be very fast and comparable to interp1 in matlab. xq is a matrix of size 501x501 with x locations we wish to interpolate. x and y are both vectors of length 4096. y holds complex data.:

```
x = linspace(-100.3,100.5,4096);
y = (cos(rand(4096,1))+j*sin(rand(4096,1)))*1/100000;
for i = 1:501
    xq(i,:) = (200).*rand(501,1)-100;
end
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `k = 1:length(x)-1` as you have `x(k+1)` there? Also, you are basically trying to optimize the presented code, right?

Comment: @Divakar - I know there was a post that you answered (I think) that efficiently finds which interval a value belonged to, given a set of `x` values... I've spent 20 minutes trying to find it here.... I hate SO and their searching system.  Once you find that post, then the linear interpolation is very easy.  This is essentially doing what `interp1` does with the `linear` option.  Do you remember seeing or answering such a post?

Comment: @rayryeng [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29101796/find-elements-meeting-any-of-a-number-of-criteria/29101879#29101879) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29061209/matlab-finding-values-within-a-matrix/29061245#29061245)?

Comment: @Divakar - Not quite :(.  Instead of trying to find it, I decided to write an answer lol.  Thank you for trying though!

Comment: @Divakar - You are right about the length statement.  It's checking consecutive pairs of points, so the last point needs to be omitted.

Comment: @starbox: Oh, you want to do all this to compute an interpolation of your values that is **less exact** than a double computation? Ignoring the reason why one would like to do that, I'll say the following instead: The main part of your question is obviously doing the calculation with something less precise than double. I don't think removing these code parts makes the question more clear then. Instead you will likely get answers that won't work with what you want to be using. Please include your actual code, so we can help you with your actual problem!

Comment: @knedlsepp, Yes, I want to do interpolation of values that is less exact than double computation. I included as much code as necessary. As long as the interpolation operation is broken apart into separate operations which can be quantized before and after performing each, then the solution works.

Comment: @starbox: I don't really understand why `quantize`ing before and after `interp1` should be a problem then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup.  What you can do is for each `xq` value, we can find which interval the value fits into.  We can use two [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) calls and take advantage of broadcasting to do this. Let's do a quick example.  Let's say we had these `x` and `xq` values:

```
x = [1 1.5 1.7 2 2.5 2.6 2.8];
xq = [1.2 1.6 2.2];
```

When doing linear interpolation, our job is to figure out which interval each `y` point belongs to for `x`.  Specifically, you want to find the index `i`, such that a value of `xq` at index `j` satisfies:

```
xq(j) >= x(i) && xq(j) < x(i+1)
```

Let's do each part of the Boolean expression separately in a vectorized manner.  For the first part, I would create a **matrix** where each column tells me which locations of `x` satisfy the `xq >= x(i)` inequality.  You can do that by:

```
ind = bsxfun(@ge, xq, x(1:end-1).');
```

What we get is:

```
ind =

   1   1   1
   0   1   1
   0   0   1
   0   0   1
   0   0   0
   0   0   0
```

The first column is for the first value of `xq`, or 1.2, the next column is 1.6, and the next column is 2.2.  This tells us which values of `x` that satisfies `xq(1) > x(i)`.  Remember, we only want to check up to the second-last element because of the `i+1` condition.  Therefore, for the first column, this means that `xq(1) >= x(1)`, which is `xq(1) >= 1`, and that's great.  For the next column, this means that both `xq(2) >= x(1)` and `xq(2) >= x(2)`, which is both `>=` than 1 and 1.5 and so on.

Now we need to do the other side of the expression:

```
ind2 = bsxfun(@lt, xq, x(2:end).')

ind2 =

   1   0   0
   1   1   0
   1   1   0
   1   1   1
   1   1   1
   1   1   1
```

This also makes sense.  For the first column this means that for `xq = 1`, every value of `x` from the second element onwards (due to the `i+1`) are **greater** than the first value of `xq`, or equivalently `xq(1) < x(i+1)`.  Now, all you have to do is combine these together:

```
ind_final = ind & ind2

ind_final = 

   1   0   0
   0   1   0
   0   0   0
   0   0   1
   0   0   0
   0   0   0
```

Therefore, this for each value of `xq`, the row location tells us **precisely** which interval each value falls into.  Therefore, for `xq = 1.2`, this fits into interval 1 or `[1,1.2]`.  For `xq = 1.6`, this fits into interval 2 or `[1.5,1.7]`.  For `xq = 2.2`, this fits into interval 4, or `[2,2.5]`.  All you have to do now is find the row locations for each of these 1s:

```
[vals,~] = find(ind_final);
```

`vals` now contains where you need to access into `x` to do your interpolation.  As such, you finally get:

```
 yq = y(vals) + (y(vals+1) - y(vals))./(x(vals+1) - x(vals)).*(xq - x(vals));
```

Note the **element-wise** operators of `./` and `.*` as we are doing this vectorized.

---

## Caveat

What we didn't take into account is what happens when you specify values that are **outside** the range of the `x` points.  What I would do is have a couple statements that check for this.  First, check to see if any `xq` values are less than the first `x` point.  If they are, let's just set them to the first output point.  Do the same thing for the other side when you have values that are greater than the last point and set the output to be the last point.  Therefore, you would have to do something like:

```
%// Allocate output array first
yq = zeros(1, numel(xq));

%// Any xq values that are less than the first value, set this to the first
yq(xq < x(1)) = y(1);

%// Any xq values that are less than the last value, set this to the last value
yq(xq >= x(end)) = y(end);

%// Get all of the other values that are not within the above ranges
ind_vals = (xq >= x(1)) & (xq < x(end));
xq = xq(ind_vals);

%// Do our work
ind = bsxfun(@ge, xq, x(1:end-1).');
ind2 = bsxfun(@lt, xq, x(2:end).');
ind_final = ind & ind2;
[vals,~] = find(ind_final);

%// Place output values in the right spots, escaping those values outside the ranges
yq(ind_vals) = y(vals) + (y(vals+1) - y(vals))./(x(vals+1) - x(vals)).*(xq - x(vals))
```

The above code should successfully do the interpolation and handle the boundary conditions.

---

To see this working, let's define a bunch of `x` and `y` values, as well as `xq` values where we wish to interpolate:

```
x = [1 1.5 1.7 2 2.5 2.6 2.8];
y = [2 3 4 5 5.5 6.6 7.7];
xq = [0.9 1 1.1 1.2 1.8 2.2 2.5 2.75 2.8 2.85];
```

Using the above, and running through the above code once I added in the range checking, we get:

```
yq =

   2.0000   2.0000   2.2000   2.4000   4.3333   5.2000   5.5000   7.4250   7.7000   7.7000
```

You can see that any `xq` values that are less than the first `x` value, we just set the output to the first `y` value.  Any values that are larger than the last `x` value, we set the output to the last `y` value.  Everything else is linearly interpolated.

Comment: Awesome, I tried using this, but when my query point, xq, is the same as my final point as x, I get the following error:>> y2=newlininterp(x,y,1:.5:10)
Error using  - 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in newlininterp (line 31)
yq = y(vals) + (y(vals+1) - y(vals))./(x(vals+1) - x(vals)).*(xq - x(vals))

Comment: @starbox - Ah... yes.  I **always** forget to account for the last point.  I'll add something small.

Comment: @starbox - OK, check it out!

Comment: Hmm it runs very slow, is there any way to speed it up? Thanks

Comment: @starbox - Are you sure?  How many points are you doing this one?  Can you provide me with a sample dataset?

Comment: Just added it to the question, let me know if there are any problems or questions.

Comment: `xq` in your question is a matrix.  I assumed it was a vector.  Can you provide more insight on what the expected shape of `xq` is?

Comment: K, added it above. By the way, I got your code to work by transpose all of my matrices and some other stuff like that, but yeah, still very slow, so maybe I didn't do it as efficiently as you might be able to.

Comment: @starbox - Given what I think you're doing, you are **looping** the above code 200 times.  Don't do that lol.  Of course it's going to be slow.

Comment: @starbox - Ah ok.  You can just convert `xq` into a vector, then reshape the output when you're done.  I'll see what I can do here.

Comment: For even just 1 iteration it takes a long time. ind1 and ind2 are pretty large, it'd be nice to do that comparisons of ge and lt in one statement, get indexes, and interpolate using those indexes somehow, maybe it would be faster?

Comment: @starbox - You could perhaps do that but I don't think it'll speed it up.  I'll have a look.

Comment: Yeah it would take a long time.  The broadcasting for `bsxfun` would create a very large matrix.  Unfortunately, I don't think I can get this to work as is as it's very memory greedy.

Comment: I couldn't get your code to work with my input data above, I can't figure out what I did wrong. Any Idea how to get it to work?

Comment: It won't work because your input data is very large. I don't have any suggestions for you.

Comment: @starbox - Thank you for accepting my answer, even though this won't work for your particular application.  `bsxfun` is very memory intensive, and so if you have a large data set you want to use for interpolation, this will crap out.  I still appreciate the rep points :)

Comment: you're welcome. I ended up using a modified version of the interp1q function for my needs. It isn't the fastest, but the operations are split apart enough for what I need.

Answer (score 1):

This should probably be a comment, but I lack the karma. 
For-loops doesn't equal slow in semi recent versions of Matlab. I have before seen cases where people jump through hoops in order to remove any loop, and end up with worse performance.

At any rate, a large part of your loop seems to be independent from *j*. Try something along the lines of this for a start. I doubt you'll see much improved performance by removing the loops, but I would love to be proved wrong :)

```
C = y(1:end-1) + (y(2:end) - y(1:end-1))./(x(2:end)-x(1:end-1))';
for j = 1:length(xq)
  for k = 1:length(x)-1
    if ((x(k) <= xq(j)) && (xq(j) < x(k+1)))
      yq(j) = C(k) * (xq(j)-x(k));
      break;
    end
  end
end
```

Using the example data, this runs about 25 % faster than your original code. Also, note that the *'* at the end of the first line is only needed if x and y have different sizes as in the example, (1,4096) versus (4096,1). Also consider pre-allocating arrays like xq and yq.

Comment: The matrix dimensions don't agree in your code. y(2:end) and y(1:end) are different lengths

Comment: Whops, sorry about that. Didn't have access to Matlab when I answered. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use matlabs built in function to do this?

```
yq = interp1(x, y, xq);
```

Comment: Because I want to modify the precision that internal operations are performed. I believe matlab will perform internal operations using double precision arithmetic, I don't want this behavior.

Comment: @starbox: I don't get what you mean by you *don't want double precision arithmetic behavior*. `interp1` is just fine if you want to do linear interpolation.

Comment: @knedlsepp, I need to control the precision manually. Think about this: what if you want to perform interpolation with a mantissa that only has 37 bits and an exponent of 4 bits? if you use interp1, all of the internal calculations are done in double precision arithmetic.

Comment: @starbox: But what datatype will you be using then? MATLAB's variable precision `vpa` doesn't work with `interp1`, but it won't work with `bsxfun` used in rayryeng's answer either.

Comment: @knedlsepp that's a very important point. I neglected to see WHY the OP wanted something like this. Another XY problem.

Comment: @knedlsepp, You have to quantize after each operation (e.g. add, mult, etc.) If quantize before and after performing addition or multiplication for example, it's like using hardware with less precision.

Comment: @rayryeng: I was thinking the exact same thing. I like to think that for us, trying to answer people's problems, we are building up our skills in understanding other's minds. This is a great good to have in life. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As I'm still not completely sure in which way you want to do the interpolation itself, here is just a little advice on how to reduce the complexity of your algorithm.
In its current form the algorithm is of complexity `O(m*n)` for `m=length(x)` and `n=length(xq)`. It is possible to reduce this to `O(m*log(m) + n*log(n))`.

In a low level language, you would first sort the vectors `xq` and `x` (and rearrange the corresponding values of `y`), then iterate through the vector `xq`. This way searching for the correct interval index `k` can be done in a more efficient way than searching from `k=1` to `length(x)`. Instead you can start your search beginning at the last found value of `k`.

MATLAB does however provide a convenient function `histc`, which does this for you. It can return those `k`-indices of the intervals the values `xq` lie in. You still need to sort `x` and `y` though.

```
%%// Find the intervals the values lie in.
[x,I] = sort(x);
y = y(I);
[~, ks] = histc(xq, x);

%%// Do the interpolation.
for j = 1:length(xq)
    k = ks(j);
    yq(j) = y(k) + (y(k+1) - y(k))/(x(k+1)-x(k)) * (xq(j)-x(k));
end
```

You might be able to vectorize the `for`-loop away, but as you didn't specify in what way you are actually doing the quantization step, I'll leave this to you. You might want to take a look at *rayryeng*'s last computation step for this though. Using this `histc` preprocessing step, it's just a matter of swapping `vals` for `ks`.

For the data-sizes listed in the question, this should give you a ~30x speedup.

Comment: @starbox: Have you tried this approach? It is roughly 30 times faster than your original approach.